# SwiftUI: Understanding .sheet / .fullScreenCover lifecycle when using constant vs @Binding initializers

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to understand how and when the .sheet and .fullScreenCover initializers are called. Below is a minimal reproducible example, where the first screen has 3 colored rectangles and the SecondView (shown via .fullScreenCover) has 1 rectangle that changes color based on the selected color from the first screen.

- When the app first loads, the color is set to .gray.
- If I tap on the green rectangle, SecondView presents with a gray rectangle. (ie. the color DIDN'T change correctly).
- If I then dismiss the SecondView and tap on the red rectangle, the SecondView presents with a red rectangle. (ie. the color DID change correctly.)

**So, I'm wondering why this set up does NOT work on the initial load, but does work on the 2nd/3rd try?**

Note: I understand this can be solved by changing the 'let selectedColor' to a @Binding variable, that's not what I'm asking.

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

    struct SegueTest: View {
        
        @State var showSheet: Bool = false
        @State var color: Color = .gray
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        color = .red
                        showSheet.toggle()
                    }
                
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        color = .green
                        showSheet.toggle()
                    }
    
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                    .fill(Color.orange)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        color = .orange
                        showSheet.toggle()
                    }
    
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
                SecondView(selectedColor: color)
            })
        }
    }
    
    struct SecondView: View {
        
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
        let selectedColor: Color // Should change to @Binding
        
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                    .fill(selectedColor)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    struct SegueTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            SegueTest()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See comments and `print` statements. Especially the `red`

```
import SwiftUI

struct SegueTest: View {
    
    @State var showSheet: Bool = false{
        didSet{
            print("showSheet :: didSet")
        }
        willSet{
            print("showSheet :: willSet")
        }
    }
    @State var color: Color = .gray{
        didSet{
            print("color :: didSet :: \(color.description)")
        }
        willSet{
            print("color :: willSet :: \(color.description)")
        }
    }
    @State var refresh: Bool = false
    init(){
        print("SegueTest " + #function)
    }
    var body: some View {
        print(#function)
        return HStack {
            //Just to see what happens when you recreate the View
            //Text(refresh.description)
            Text(color.description)
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("SegueTest :: onTapGesture :: red")
                    //Changing the color
                    color = .red
                    //Refreshed SegueTest reloads function
                    //refresh.toggle()
                    showSheet.toggle()
                }
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("SegueTest :: onTapGesture :: green")
                    //Changing the color
                    color = .green
                    showSheet.toggle()
                }
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                .fill(Color.orange)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("SegueTest :: onTapGesture :: orange")
                    //Changing the color
                    color = .orange
                    showSheet.toggle()
                }
            
        }
        //This part is likely created when SegueTest is created and since a struct is immutable it keeps the original value
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
            SecondView(selectedColor: color)
        })
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    //struct is immutable
    let selectedColor: Color // Should change to @Binding
    init(selectedColor: Color){
        print("SecondView " + #function)
        self.selectedColor = selectedColor
        print("SecondView :: struct :: selectedColor = \(self.selectedColor.description)" )
        print("SecondView :: parameter :: selectedColor = \(selectedColor.description)" )
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                .fill(selectedColor)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
    
}

struct SegueTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SegueTest()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful - thank you. Why does refresh.toggle() reload SegueTest but changing the color does not? Both are @State variables. Is there a way to print when SegueTest is reloaded?

Comment: It would if it was referenced in the `SegueTest` change `Text(refresh.description)` to `Text(color.description)` and comment out `refresh.toggle()` and `@State var refresh: Bool = false`. I just used refresh for explanation/test or maybe habit. Put a `print` in the `body`. See the code

Comment: Ohhh I see it now. So if I also comment out the Text(), the view won't re-render and the color doesn't change. But by adding that Text(), the view is forced to re-render before the segue... right?

Comment: Yes, that is how it works. `@Binding` forces the rendering in the `SecondView` so it works every time and it isn't dependent on some other refresh.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to figure out. ... so, if I comment out Text(), it doesn't re-render... but on the 2nd/3rd try it will re-render. Any idea what causes that?

Comment: Probably SwiftUI's preloading behavior. There is a lot of prediction with SwiftUI. That would definitely be something to ask Apple to get the inner workings (During WWDC so you don't lose a code specific question opportunity or maybe in the Apple forums). It also doesn't change if you hit the same color over and over again. It only learns after you hit the second color.

Comment: Yea, I saw that haha. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using your @State color inside SegueView, which will not reload your view on State change. Just include your @State somewhere in the code, which will force it to rerender at then update the sheet, with the correct color.

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
    .fill(color == .red ? Color.red : Color.red) //<< just use dump color variable here
```

If you do not include your color state somewhere in the code, it won't re render your SegueView, hence you still pass the old color gray to your `SecondView`.

Or even pass your colors as Binding your your Second View..

```
SecondView(selectedColor: $color)

@Binding var selectedColor: Color
```