# Why does this SwiftUI code show "Empty" in the destination screen?

Tags: swiftui

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showModal = false
    @State var text = "Empty"
    var body: some View {
        Button("show text") {
            text = "Filled"
            showModal = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
            VStack {
                Text(text)
                Button("print text") {
                    print(text)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that when the "show text" button was tapped, the value of `text` would be set to "Filled" and `showModal` would be set to true, so that the screen specified in `sheet` would be displayed and the word "Filled" would be shown on that screen.

I thought it would show "Filled", but it actually showed "Empty".

Furthermore, when I printed the `text` using the `print text` button, the console displayed "Filled".

Why does it work like this?

What am I missing to display the value I set when I tap the button on the destination screen?

using Xcode12.4, Xcode12.5

---

Add the code for the new pattern.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var number = 0
    @State var showModal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("set number 1") {
                 number = 1
                 showModal = true
                print("set number = \(number)")
             }

            Button("set number 2") {
                 number = 2
                 showModal = true
                print("set number = \(number)")
             }

            Button("add number") {
                number += 1
                showModal = true
                print("add number = \(number)")
             }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
            VStack {
                let _ = print("number = \(number)")
                Text("\(number)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, when I first tap "set number 1" or "set number 2", the destination screen shows "0". No matter how many times you tap the same button, "0" will be displayed.

However, if you tap "set number 2" after tapping "set number 1", it will work correctly and display "2". If you continue to tap "set number 1", "1" will be displayed and the app will work correctly.

When you tap "add number" for the first time after the app is launched, "0" will still be displayed, but if you tap "add number" again, "2" will be displayed and the app will count up correctly.

This shows that the rendering of the destination screen can be started even when the @State variable is updated, but only when the @State variable is referenced first in the destination screen, it does not seem to be referenced properly.

Can anyone explain why it behaves this way?

Or does this look like a bug in SwiftUI?

Comment: SwiftUI preloads sheets I think - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65281559/swiftui-understanding-sheet-fullscreencover-lifecycle-when-using-constant-v

Comment: @aheze Thank you for your suggestion.

Unlike the code in the link, my code uses the @State variable `text` in the transition screen. If it's preloading, why doesn't it detect the change in `text` and reload the screen? How can I get it to reload?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: Understanding .sheet / .fullScreenCover lifecycle when using constant vs @Binding initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65281559/swiftui-understanding-sheet-fullscreencover-lifecycle-when-using-constant-v)

Comment: If you use the projected value you will see the change. It doesn’t show the change because showing the sheet prevents the struct from being reloaded. It is just sitting there waiting until there is a reload. You can get the most current value by using `@Binding` in the sheet content or by using the sheet with `item` as a parameter

Answer (score 2):

Since **iOS 14**,  there are a couple of main ways of presenting a `Sheet`.

Firstly, for your example, you need to create a separate `View` and pass your property to a `Binding`, which will then be correctly updated when the `Sheet` is presented.

```
// ContentView
Button { ... }
.sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
    SheetView(text: $text)
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)
            Button("print text") {
                print(text)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The other way of doing it is by using an `Optional` identifiable object, and when that object has a value the sheet will be presented.  Doing that, you do not need to separately manage the state of whether the sheet is showing.

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var item: Item? = nil

    var body: some View {
        Button("show text") {
            item = Item(text: "Filled")
        }
        .sheet(item: $item, content: { item in
            VStack {
                Text(item.text)
                Button("print text") {
                    print(item.text)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

I already know that it works well if I separate the `View` and pass it using `@Binding`.

However, I am not convinced that using @State will not work.

I have added another new code to the question.

Can you explain why the code you added works like this?

Comment: It is because when the view first loads, it is pre-loading the sheet closure based on the current state of the view.  After you present the view and dismiss it, the state is refreshed, which is why you are only seeing the issue the first time the sheet is presented.  I am not sure if that is intended behaviour and it may be worth reporting the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

I don't know why, but I understood that the first sheet that is preloaded cannot get the updated value of the state variable and displays the value before the update, while the sheet that is closed and re-displayed can get the updated value of the state variable, so it works correctly thereafter.

Based on this, I tried many things and found a way to display the updated value of the state variable on the first sheet that is displayed.

I have responded to that method as a self-answer. However, I think this method is a little tricky.

Comment: Otherwise (and for iOS 13 anyway) the solution is to move the item property from the view to a model. Make it a Published property in an ObervableObject class instead of a State property in the view. This is indeed because sheets are preloaded from the view struct and do not see the change inside the struct (because the change happens after the sheet is preloaded).

Answer (score 0):

By adding the following code, I was able to display the word "Filled" in the destination screen.

- Declare the `updateDetector` as a @State variable.
- Update the `updateDetector` onAppear of the View in the sheet.
- Reference the `updateDetector` somewhere in the View in the sheet.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showModal = false
    @State var updateDetector = false
    @State var text = "Empty"
    var body: some View {
        Button("show text") {
            text = "Filled"
            print("set text to \(text)")
            showModal = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
            let _ = print("render text = \(text)")
            VStack {
                Text(text)
                // use EmptyView to access updateDetector
                if updateDetector {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                // update updateDetector
                print("toggle updateDetector")
                updateDetector.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, after rendering the initial value at the time of preloading, the process of updating the `updateDetector` onAppear will work, the View will be rendered again, and the updated value of the @State variable will be displayed.

When you tap the "show text" button in the above code, the following will be displayed in the console and "Filled" will be shown on the screen.

```
set text to Filled
render text = Empty
toggle updateDetector
render text = Filled
```

I'm still not convinced why I can't get the updated value of the @State variable in the first preloaded sheet. So I will report this to Apple via the Feedback Assistant.