# i cannot select an item firstly if i do not click to another item

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, foreach

In SwiftUI i work on my app and just realized this strange behaviour with ForEach.

My first selection always seems *nil* until i click on a different item. Despite i see on every click i successfully save the item and pass to the sheet. If i pass the item to a subview, that works fine, but with **.sheet** doesn't. What i do wrong?

I have tested on XCode 13.4.1, XCode 14 beta 2.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
   let id =  UUID()
   var name: String
}

class Data: ObservableObject {
   @Published var items : [Item]
   init(items: [Item] = [
      Item(name: "A1"),
      Item(name: "A2"),
      Item(name: "A3"),
      Item(name: "A4")
   ]) {
      self.items = items
   }
}

struct ContentView: View {
   @StateObject var model = Data()
   @State var showDetail = false
   @State private var selectedItem: Item?
   
   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         List {
            ForEach( model.items, id:\.self ) { item in
               Text( item.name )
               .onTapGesture {
                  selectedItem = item
                  print("\(item) \(selectedItem)")
                  showDetail.toggle()
               }
            }
         }
      }
      .sheet(isPresented: $showDetail) {
         VStack {
            if let selectedItem = selectedItem {
               Text(selectedItem.name)
            } else {
               Text("Nothing selected \(selectedItem?.name ?? "-")")
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
      ContentView()
   }
}
```

Comment: Use `sheet(item:)`

Comment: it solves the problem, but i still do not understand, where i lost the value of selectedItem, and why i lost it in only the first selection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65281559/swiftui-understanding-sheet-fullscreencover-lifecycle-when-using-constant-v/65281850#65281850

Comment: It isn't lost, it is a timing/efficiency thing it is the projected value with your current setup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but if i put following line to your ContentView

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
```

the problem (with first item) disappears.
Tested on macOS 12.4 and XCode 13.4.1

Comment: Likely because it is triggering a refresh. I wouldn’t count on this as a long term solution. SwiftUI is becoming more efficient with time.