# UISheetPresentationController in SwiftUI doesn't update body content

Tags: swiftui

I am using this implementation for showing `UISheetPresentationController` in SwiftUI

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 15.0, macCatalyst 15.0,*)
extension View {
    func adaptiveSheet<T: View>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, detents : [UISheetPresentationController.Detent] = [.medium(), .large()], largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier: UISheetPresentationController.Detent.Identifier? = .medium, prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge: Bool = false, prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight: Bool = true, prefersGrabberVisible: Bool = false, disableSwipeToDismiss: Bool = false, preferredCornerRadius: CGFloat? = nil, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> T)-> some View {
        print("\(#function) :: isPresented == \(isPresented)")
        return modifier(AdaptiveSheet<T>(isPresented: isPresented, detents : detents, largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier: largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier, prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge: prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge, prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight: prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight, prefersGrabberVisible: prefersGrabberVisible, disableSwipeToDismiss: disableSwipeToDismiss, preferredCornerRadius: preferredCornerRadius, sheetContent: content))
    }
}
@available(iOS 15.0, macCatalyst 15.0,*)
struct AdaptiveSheet<T: View>: ViewModifier {
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let detents : [UISheetPresentationController.Detent]
    let largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier: UISheetPresentationController.Detent.Identifier?
    let prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge: Bool
    let prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight: Bool
    let prefersGrabberVisible: Bool
    let disableSwipeToDismiss: Bool
    let preferredCornerRadius: CGFloat?
    @ViewBuilder let sheetContent: T
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        print("AdaptiveSheet :: \(#function) :: isPresented == \(isPresented)")
        return content.overlay(
            CustomSheet_UI(isPresented: $isPresented, detents: detents, largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier: largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier, prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge: prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge, prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight: prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight, prefersGrabberVisible: prefersGrabberVisible, disableSwipeToDismiss: disableSwipeToDismiss,preferredCornerRadius: preferredCornerRadius, content: {sheetContent}).frame(width: 0, height: 0)
            
        )
        
            .onChange(of: isPresented, perform: { value in
                print("AdaptiveSheet :: onChange :: isPresented == \(value)")
            })
        
        //}
    }
}

@available(iOS 15.0, macCatalyst 15.0,*)
struct CustomSheet_UI<T: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var detents : [UISheetPresentationController.Detent] = [.medium(), .large()]
    var largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier: UISheetPresentationController.Detent.Identifier? = .medium
    var prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge: Bool = false
    var prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight: Bool = true
    var prefersGrabberVisible: Bool = false
    var disableSwipeToDismiss: Bool = false
    var preferredCornerRadius: CGFloat?
    @ViewBuilder let content: T
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CustomSheetViewController<T> {
        print("CustomSheet_UI :: \(#function) :: isPresented == \(isPresented)")
        let vc = CustomSheetViewController(coordinator: context.coordinator, detents : detents, largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier: largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier, prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge:  prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge, prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight: prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight, prefersGrabberVisible: prefersGrabberVisible, disableSwipeToDismiss: disableSwipeToDismiss, preferredCornerRadius: preferredCornerRadius, content: {content})
        return vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CustomSheetViewController<T>, context: Context) {
        print("CustomSheet_UI :: \(#function) :: isPresented == \(isPresented)")
        print("CustomSheet_UI :: \(#function) :: context.coordinator.parent.isPresented == \(context.coordinator.parent.isPresented)")
        if isPresented {
            uiViewController.presentModalView()
        }else{
            uiViewController.dismissModalView()
        }
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {
        var parent: CustomSheet_UI
        var isPresented: Bool = false
        init(_ parent: CustomSheet_UI) {
            print("CustomSheet_UI :: \(#function) :: parent.isPresented == \(parent.isPresented)")
            
            self.parent = parent
        }
        //Adjust the variable when the user dismisses with a swipe
        func presentationControllerDidDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
            print("CustomSheet_UI.Coordinator :: \(#function) :: parent.isPresented == \(parent.isPresented)")
            if parent.isPresented{
                parent.isPresented = false
            }
        }
        
    }
}

@available(iOS 15.0, macCatalyst 15.0,*)
class CustomSheetViewController<Content: View>: UIViewController {
    let content: Content
    var coordinator: CustomSheet_UI<Content>.Coordinator
    let detents : [UISheetPresentationController.Detent]
    let largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier: UISheetPresentationController.Detent.Identifier?
    let prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge: Bool
    let prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight: Bool
    let prefersGrabberVisible: Bool
    let disableSwipeToDismiss: Bool
    let preferredCornerRadius: CGFloat?
    private var isLandscape: Bool = UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape
    init(coordinator: CustomSheet_UI<Content>.Coordinator, detents : [UISheetPresentationController.Detent] = [.medium(), .large()], largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier: UISheetPresentationController.Detent.Identifier? = .medium, prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge: Bool = false, prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight: Bool = true, prefersGrabberVisible: Bool, disableSwipeToDismiss: Bool, preferredCornerRadius: CGFloat?, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        print("CustomSheetViewController :: \(#function) :: isPresented == \(coordinator.parent.isPresented)")
        self.content = content()
        self.coordinator = coordinator
        self.detents = detents
        self.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier
        self.prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight = prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight
        self.prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge = prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge
        self.prefersGrabberVisible = prefersGrabberVisible
        self.disableSwipeToDismiss = disableSwipeToDismiss
        self.preferredCornerRadius = preferredCornerRadius
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: .main)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func dismissModalView(){
        print("CustomSheetViewController :: \(#function) :: isPresented == \(coordinator.parent.isPresented)")
        
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func presentModalView(){
        print("CustomSheetViewController :: \(#function) :: isPresented == \(coordinator.parent.isPresented)")
        
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: content)
        //allows background color to be decided by SwiftUI content.
        // Incase you want to use a Material that gives transparency
        hostingController.view.backgroundColor = nil
        hostingController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        hostingController.presentationController?.delegate = coordinator as UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate
        hostingController.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
        hostingController.isModalInPresentation = disableSwipeToDismiss
        
        if let hostPopover = hostingController.popoverPresentationController {
            hostPopover.sourceView = super.view
            
            let sheet = hostPopover.adaptiveSheetPresentationController
            //As of 13 Beta 4 if .medium() is the only detent in landscape error occurs
            sheet.detents = (isLandscape ? [.large()] : detents)
            sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier =
            largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier
            sheet.prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge =
            prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge
            sheet.prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight =
            prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight
            sheet.widthFollowsPreferredContentSizeWhenEdgeAttached = true
            sheet.prefersGrabberVisible = prefersGrabberVisible
            sheet.preferredCornerRadius = preferredCornerRadius
        }
        if presentedViewController == nil{
            present(hostingController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    /// To compensate for l orientation
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            isLandscape = true
            self.presentedViewController?.popoverPresentationController?.adaptiveSheetPresentationController.detents = [.large()]
        } else {
            isLandscape = false
            self.presentedViewController?.popoverPresentationController?.adaptiveSheetPresentationController.detents = detents
        }
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        
    }
}
```

when I change `iOn` value, it doesn't change the content. Please consider the following demo view

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @State var isOn = false
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Toggle("Is on?", isOn: $isOn)

            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .adaptiveSheet(isPresented: self.$isOn) {
            let _ = print("sheet => rendered with value:", isOn)
            if isOn {
                let _ = print("sheet => inside isOn = true condition:", isOn)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
            } else {
                let _ = print("sheet => inside isOn = false condition:", isOn)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

changing `isOn` value triggers the following line

```
let _ = print("sheet => inside isOn = false condition:", isOn)
```

but for some reason the UI doesn't get updated. The red color persists no matter what I do.

Comment: This code feels centuries old… put the content in a subview with a.Binding for the variable you want to change. The reason it doesn’t change is similar to the use for sheet(item:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: Understanding .sheet / .fullScreenCover lifecycle when using constant vs @Binding initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65281559/swiftui-understanding-sheet-fullscreencover-lifecycle-when-using-constant-v)

Comment: @loremipsum but if I used .sheet, it will works fine