Array showing incorrect data in SwiftUI sheet
Here's the code
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {

@State private var Items = ["Apple", "Microsoft", "Google"]
@State private var presentSheet = Bool()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(Items) { item in 
                    Text(item)
                        .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                            Button("Show", systemImage: "eye" {
                                presentSheet.toggle
                            }
                            .tint(Color.yellow)
                        }

                    .sheet(isPresented: $presentSheet) {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("MyView")
        }
    }
}

The sheet only shows the last item in the array, when it should show the item that opened the sheet
I tried making a sheet view that only displays the text you selected
I was expecting it to show the single item, but instead just showed the last item in the array

You have several compilation errors in the posted code, is it really the code you are running?

use sheet(item:)

@loremipsum I am not sure if he can do use that given his setup, because .sheet(item: requires a binding - and the ForEach loop item doesn't give him a binding.

@AndreiG that is the solution for this setup. People ask this same exact question at least once a week.

I am not saying it isn't the solution, just not sure if he can directly use it without additional changes like adding a state that gives him a binding. If you think he can, please provide an answer with supporting code so we can all learn :)

I know you can use a binding in the loop, like ForEach($items...) { $item in, but in this case, the $item will be a Binding<String> and the .sheet(item: requires an optional: Binding<()?>. So now even I am curious about your suggestion.

Instead of presentSheet, use selectedItem to use .sheet(item: $selectedItem). I added the @MainActor annotation for safety reasons, and you should use it, too. If you compile it with Swift 6, you will get a warning that you should use @retroactive (SE-0364) to conform String to Identifiable.
extension String: Identifiable {
    public var id: Self { self }
}

@MainActor
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var items = ["Apple", "Microsoft", "Google"]
    @State private var selectedItem: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
                    .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                        Button("Show", systemImage: "eye") {
                            selectedItem = item
                        }
                        .tint(.yellow)
                    }
            }
            .navigationTitle("MyView")
            .sheet(item: $selectedItem) { string in
                Text(string)
            }
        }
    }
}


Note: Please don't change the code in other people's questions--if you find issues with it, you should report them in comments or include them in an answer that resolves the problem with those issues.

UPDATED: Revised the code in light of the discussion in the comments and points raised by @loremipsum. I am adding this answer as an alternative solution to using .sheet(item:  as shown in the other answer, for educational purposes.
First, note that by convention, your Items array should be items (with initial lowercase), since it's not a a class, struct or enum name.
The code as you had it couldn't work, because the sheet doesn't show the item at the time the ForEach loop runs. It shows some content at the time the button is pressed (or, whatever item was in the loop at the moment the modifier was attached).
To fix it, have the button set a state (selectedItem) with the value of the item and read the state when the sheet opens. Then, clear the state when the sheet is dismissed.
Now how and when you read the state is important to understand, especially when working with .sheet and depending on which initializer you use.
The previous version of the code I posted had a bug, as pointed out by @loremipsum in the comments, which caused for the sheet to initially open with no value.
Since the other answer shows a working version using the .sheet(item: initializer, I will show how to make it reliably work using the .sheet(isPresented: initializer.
Note also that the code was restructured to have the sheet modifier outside the loop, since there is no need for each array item to have its own sheet modifier if they all read from the same shared state value anyway:
import SwiftUI

struct SheetItemView: View {
    
    @State private var items = ["Apple", "Microsoft", "Google"]
    @State private var selectedItem: String = ""
    @State private var presentSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id:\.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                        .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                            Button {
                                selectedItem = item
                            } label: {
                                Label("Show", systemImage: "eye")
                            }
                            .tint(Color.yellow)
                        }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("MyView")
            .onChange(of: selectedItem){ 
                if !selectedItem.isEmpty {
                    presentSheet = true
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $presentSheet, onDismiss: { 
                selectedItem  = ""
            }) {
                Text(selectedItem)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SheetItemView()
}

It's important to understand when using isPresented, that the sheet and its contents will not update when the value of selectedItem changes - unless something causes the entire view or parts of the view that include the ones where the .sheet modifier is added to be redrawn. Or, unless you make sure that the sheet is presented as the result of a change in selectedItem.
Code that would force the view to redraw and update the sheet to reflect the selectedItem accurately, without the initial nil value bug, could be a number of things.
For example, updating the navigation title with the name of the selected item:
.navigationTitle("MyView: \(selectedItem)")

Or, simply reading and printing the value of the selected item at a higher level before the List is called:
    //...
    NavigationStack {
       let _ = print("Selected item is : \(selectedItem) ")
       List {
    //...

Or even an empty .onChange modifier:
    .onChange(of: selectedItem){ 
        //...
    }

Evidently, printing to the console in order to make something work is not at all proper and should not be adopted. Instead, the code should explicitly define its purpose.
This can be done by showing the sheet as the result of a change in selected item and only if the change did not result in an empty value (which is the case when the sheet is dismissed and selectedItem is set to empty):
    .onChange(of: selectedItem){ 
        if !selectedItem.isEmpty {
            presentSheet = true
        }
    }

The above could also be written using the two input parameters trailing closure version of .onChange:
    .onChange(of: selectedItem){ oldValue, newValue in
        if !newValue.isEmpty {
            presentSheet = true
        }
    }

In the main code above, the selectedItem was intentionally kept as a non-optional, for simplicity. But, if you did want or need to work with optional values, you'll need to account for nil values.
So if selected item was optional: @State private var selectedItem: String?, the .onChange would use conditional binding:
    .onChange(of: selectedItem){ 
        if let item = selectedItem, item != "" {
            presentSheet = true
        }
    }

And the display of the name in the sheet would also need to be changed:
    .sheet(isPresented: $presentSheet, onDismiss: {
        selectedItem  = nil
    }) {
        if let item = selectedItem, item != "" {
            Text(item)
        }
    }

In conclusion, the simplest way to go about it given your code example is using the .sheet(item:  as shown in the other answer.
But, I wanted to put this together to explain, because there can be cases when you need to set a state with a specific item and take action based on that item and having this understanding will come in handy. I'll also be able to refer to it myself later when I will lose hair the next time a form editor or a link opens with a nil value when one was expected ;).

So 2 variables and a closure to do what sheet(item does?

@loremipsum I commented on your other comment with details. Unless you will provide an answer with code to support your argument, please don't downvote my answers or any other answers that do provide a solution to the OP's question.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:) just look at the documentation and the other answer

I mentioned in a previous comment that using .sheet(item: will work with additional changes like adding the supporting selectedItem state. Since the other answer already shows that approach, my answer shows an alternative more aligned with the OP's original method using isPresented to indicate that the OP's issue is not with how the .sheet is invoked, but with his expectation that the loop's item will be displayed in the sheet. The other answer does not explain this concept, which I believe is essential for someone who is admittedly learning SwiftUI.

Just because I find this whole interaction hilarious especially your spin. Have you actually tested your code? The first time you swipe and click the sheet will be empty. This is a known limitation since SwiftUI 1, this exact scenario is the use case for sheet(item:) your solution would work for an infinite number of scenarios but not here, it isn't an alternative because it will always show a stale value the first time and randomly thereafter.

Well, should have mentioned the first swipe empty thing from the get go, since I obviously missed it! And that makes sense but it isn't mentioned anywhere. Although, I've used this method before including in the app I am working on, without this issue. Is it because I am working with (identifiable) SwiftData model objects for the selectedItem?

Identifiable doesn’t have anything to do with this. The reason SwiftData doesn’t have this issue is because of the new Observation framework.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65281559/swiftui-understanding-sheet-fullscreencover-lifecycle-when-using-constant-v/65281850#65281850

I see what's happening. The real issue is that depending on where it's added in the hierarchy and whether anything above it drives a redraw due to changes in selectedItem, .sheet(isPresented (and its content) will not update until the redraw happens. Meaning that if anything does cause a redraw (like updating the navigation title based on the selectedItem, or printing to the console the value of selectedItem, or even an empty .onChange modifier), it will work fine. I have updated my answer in consideration of this, with hopefully a reliably working version, for educational purposes.

Yes, that is the essence. That is what I came up with a long time ago on that link. Depending on the iOS version the subsequent behavior as changed over the years but the first is always stale.  You can "fix" it by using @Binding in the sheet too. That is the simplest version.
